# Soot: How to analyze a java file in a package?

Tags: java, static-analysis, call-graph, soot

I have two java files under the `tests` directory.
I use the following code to set up Soot for further analysis(i.e., construct a call graph) but meet an error of `are the packages set properly?`.

`Main.java`:

```java
public class Main {
    static void setupSoot() {
        Options.v().set_prepend_classpath(true);
        Options.v().set_process_dir(Collections.singletonList("./tests"));
        Options.v().set_whole_program(true);
        Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();
    }

    // Following function also doesn't work and has a similar error message
    //static void setupSoot() {
    //    Options.v().set_prepend_classpath(true);
    //    Options.v().set_process_dir(Collections.singletonList("./tests"));
    //    Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport("FooBar");
    //}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setupSoot();
        // ....
    }
}
```

And I get the following error message:

```bash
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: couldn't find class: FooBar are the packages set properly?
    at soot.JastAddInitialResolver.resolveFromJavaFile(JastAddInitialResolver.java:119)
    at soot.JavaClassSource.resolve(JavaClassSource.java:69)
    at soot.SootResolver.bringToHierarchyUnchecked(SootResolver.java:253)
    at soot.SootResolver.bringToHierarchy(SootResolver.java:221)
    at soot.SootResolver.bringToSignatures(SootResolver.java:292)
    at soot.SootResolver.bringToBodies(SootResolver.java:332)
    at soot.SootResolver.processResolveWorklist(SootResolver.java:171)
    at soot.SootResolver.resolveClass(SootResolver.java:141)
    at soot.Scene.loadClass(Scene.java:1009)
    at soot.Scene.loadClassAndSupport(Scene.java:994)
    at soot.Scene.loadNecessaryClasses(Scene.java:1822)
    at Main.setupSoot(Main.java:18)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

If I complie two test files into `.class` files then I will get following error message:

```bash
Exception in thread "main" soot.SootResolver$SootClassNotFoundException: couldn't find class: tests.FooBar (is your soot-class-path set properly?)
    at soot.SootResolver.bringToHierarchyUnchecked(SootResolver.java:245)
    at soot.SootResolver.bringToHierarchy(SootResolver.java:221)
    at soot.SootResolver.bringToSignatures(SootResolver.java:292)
    at soot.SootResolver.bringToBodies(SootResolver.java:332)
    at soot.SootResolver.processResolveWorklist(SootResolver.java:171)
    at soot.SootResolver.resolveClass(SootResolver.java:141)
    at soot.Scene.loadClass(Scene.java:1009)
    at soot.Scene.loadClassAndSupport(Scene.java:994)
    at soot.Scene.loadNecessaryClasses(Scene.java:1822)
    at Main.setupSoot(Main.java:18)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

I beleive that `soot prepend_classpath` is true since it works well when two test files are not in the package (i.e., remove `package tests` from both files).

Two files in `tests` directory are as follows:

`Pack.java`:

```java
package tests;
public class Pack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int s = 10;
    }
}
```

`FooBar.java`

```java
package tests;

public class FooBar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooBar callFooBar = new FooBar();
        callFooBar.foo(10);
    }

    void foo(int a) {
        bar(a);
    }

    void bar(int a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            i += a;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The issue is that the `path` of the test files is wrong.
Now my project structure is as follows:

```bash
-ProjectRoot
|--src
    |--Main.java
|--testers
    |--easycase
        |--FooBar.java
        |--Pack.java
```

and My `Main.java`:

```java
public class Main {
    static void setupSoot() {
        Options.v().set_prepend_classpath(true);
        // Options.v().set_soot_classpath("xxxxx:xxxxx/xxxxx.jar") // For external packages
        Options.v().set_process_dir(Collections.singletonList("./testers"));
        Options.v().set_whole_program(true);
        Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setupSoot();
        Scene.v().loadAndSupport("esaycase.FooBar");
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Note that the first line is `package easycase;` for both test files.